# Jar file not executing in ksh cygwin

Tags: cygwin, ksh

My Java team provided me a jar file and below command to execute in Cygwin environment:

```
java -DmoduleName="GBL" -jar G:/CSFBApps/planning/bin/planning_aura.jar  G:/CSFBApps/planning/bin/resources
```

This command when I trigger from command prompt working fine but when I put the same in sample KSH script:

```
java -DmoduleName="GBL" -jar G:/CSFBApps/planning/bin/planning_aura.jar  G:/CSFBApps/planning/bin/resources

echo $?
```

it just executes and showing 1 (which i think not executed).

So i believe KSH not invoking jar, please help me.

Comment: In Cygwin,  G:/  may need to be /cygdrive/g/

Comment: I tried it as well   java -DmoduleName="GBL" -jar /cygdrive/g/CSFBApps/planning/bin/planning_aura.jar /cygdrive/g/CSFBApps/planning/bin/resources - It then shows error as " Unable to access jar file /cygdrive/g/CSFBApps/planning/bin/planning_aura.jar - Files are present correctly in paths and i gave 777 permissions on these files still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Checkout other posts showing how to use `cygpath` with java in cygwin